# How to display relationship properties on the graph edge

Tags: neo4j

I want to display the properties of a relationship on the graph. I have changed the properties in the Grass file (Caption value). It is working for Nodes nut not relationship.

```
relationship.uses {
  caption: '{grocery}';
  shaft-width: 2px;
}
```

Any idea on how to display the values of "grocery" on the edge.

Comment: the snippet above is correct, just tried myself. Maybe it gets overridden somewhere later in the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

That looks right. Sure you uploaded the grass file?  Are your relationships in UPPER_CASE?  the grass file is case sensitive.

Here is what I did. Using Neo 3.0.3 Enterprise.
I found a relationship in the browser.

```
match ()-[r:HAS_STYLE]-() return r
```

I set a property for that relationship.

```
match ()-[r:HAS_STYLE]-() set r.points=id(r)  //set points to the object id
```

I went back to the Neo Browser and selected the Relationship HAS_STYLE and selected 'points' as the display and this was put in the grass stylesheet

```
relationship.HAS_STYLE 
    {caption: '{points}';
  }
```

The outcome is shown here
 [Style Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxS3l.png)

So I went back and added the width to 4px and the points still show as the label.
I d/l and edited grass file to

```
relationship.has_style 
        {caption: '{points}';
        shaft-width: 4px;
      }
```

and the old behaviour reverted.

Check grass file and make sure it is case correct?